# Why does the program fail to add a field with my playerID in the json on my economy discord bot? (KeyError)

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

So what I did till now is, I added a register command which would look if the user's discord ID is in the .json file. If it isn't, it just adds it and also adds 2 attributes called "Wallet" and "Bank" and sets their values to the starting ones.

So the code for it is:

```
    @bot.command()
async def register(ctx):
    oh = False
    await register_acc(ctx.author)

    if (oh == False):
        ctx.send(f'You already have an account dum dum')
    else:
        ctx.send(f'You have successfully registered an account.')

async def register_acc(user):
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] = 0

    with open("users.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True
```

Error I get:

> File "C:\Users\janvf\Desktop\Bob\main.py", line 79, in register
> await register_acc(ctx.author)
>
> File "C:\Users\janvf\Desktop\Bob\main.py", line 93, in  register_acc users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = 0 KeyError: '*my discord
> id*'

Is there something very obvious I am missing?
I tried writing the json a bit different but then realized I did it completely wrong as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the else statement to this:

```
else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {"Wallet": 0, "Bank": 0}
```

The `KeyError` is caused because `users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] = 0` is trying to change the value of the key "Bank" in the dictionary `users[str(user.id)]` which does not exist. Instead, create the key `users[str(user.id)]` and set it to a dictionary containing the value of "Wallet" and "Bank" as shown above.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm and I now understand what the problem was and how to resolve it.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error lies here

> await register_acc(ctx.author)

I imagine this returns None in your code, because ctx does not have an attribute of author.
You'd have to change this line to

> await register_acc(ctx.message.author)

This will pass a Member object to your `register_acc` method

Check the documentation on discordpy API [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#message)

Comment: I had a look at the docs and it seems `ctx` does have an `author` attribute, so I don't think that's the problem. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author